# Anyone gotten 10.7.2 to bind properly to Active Directory in a multi-domain environment?

Tags: network, active-directory, macos

I work for an international non-profit that has Active Directory with multiple domains. (A bunch of them.) We can't get Lion (10.7.2) to bind to it properly. Has anyone been successful in getting AD to work in Lion 10.7.2? We have a bunch of new Macs and can't get them on the network. We'll be testing AdmitMac this week, but would rather not pay more than $100 a machine to get them hooked up.

Comment: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4767 says a change in 10.7.2 was to ' Improve Active Directory and LDAP integration.'. I guess you need to try to find what exactly changed.

Comment: As I understand it, the first beta for 10.7.2 fixed it, but then they broke it before release. It works in single-domain networks, but not multi-domain networks. It's beyond me. I'm a photo editor, not an IT guy. :)

Comment: What resources do you need on the domain that you need to actually join for?

Comment: Single sign-on. Logging into network shares. Share Point. Exchange Server. It's a mostly Windows-based company with thousands of PCs, and about 65 Macs.

Answer (score 1):

[MacWindows](http://www.macwindows.com/Lion-10_7_3-update-focuses-on-ADand-file-sharing-bugs.html) has a lot of good feedback about this issue.  In my own testing I've found that 10.7.3 has certainly improved network logins on AD2003-bound Macs, though its still not as reliable (or fast) as I'd like.

As always, contact your SE and leave [feedback](http://www.apple.com/feedback/) about your issues.

Comment: Yes, my advice would be to upgrade them all to 10.7.3 or even better up to 10.8 where AD binding started working better again. My favourite has always been 10.6.8 where it was a dream.